# Displaying the contents of the file on the Main window

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am working on a project where i want to display the contents of the file on my main window instead of creating another widget for window

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("Python")
def perm_file():
    with open('/home/prajwal/Desktop/GUI/music/AndroidManifest.xml','r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')
    top = Toplevel()
    l = Listbox(top, height=600, width=650, bg="grey", activestyle="dotbox", font="Arial", fg="black")
    top.geometry("700x250")
    co = 0
    for c, node in enumerate(nodes):
        co += 1
        l.insert(c,node.getAttribute('android:name'))
        l.insert(0, f'Count = {co}')
    l.pack()
```

This is the code. I want the output of this code to be displayed on the main window instead of displaying it on the `top = Toplevel()` window.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix your source indentation.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What's stopping you from doing what you want? Your question mentions a `Toplevel` but your code doesn't have one.

Comment: 2 min ill edit it

Comment: In the code above i want the output of the function to be displayed on root = Tk() window instead of top = Toplevel() window

Comment: and what exactly is stopping You from doing that? can't You just add `root` as parent/master?

Comment: I did that but the listbox Is getting displayed at the bottom of the root window and not at the top...how do I rectify that

Comment: Try `l.pack(before=w)` where `w` is the widget at the top of the root window.

Comment: It says name w is not defined

Comment: Can anybody help me with it?